# How to control an Android service?

Tags: android, service, timer, timertask

I'm currently developing my first android application.
I want the user of my application to be able to activate "automatic update of data" which means that some data should be refreshed every x minutes. I've created a service which is started by

```
service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);
```

and I'm using a TimerTask within the service to periodically refresh the data.

```
timer = new Timer();

TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        refreshData();
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt,0,interval);
```

I've noticed that the service can be restarted now and then. How can I ensure that refreshData(); is run every interval minute (not more or less)? If the user changes the interval (preference) how do a kill the current timer(task) and start a new one? Right now it seems to start a new one but not killing the old making refreshData() to execute according to two intervals.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm new to android developing also so take everything i say with a grain of salt)

Well it looks to me like you have a lot of thinking to do about structure. There are different ways to communicate with the service. I think that the best option would be to broadcast an intent, make the service receive the intent and change the interval based on the information received from the intent.

Comment: Hi, can your explain (or point me to a tutorial) how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't answered quickly. Im still figuring out how to use this site. Anyways, check out the remote messenger

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you had to press shift-enter to enter a new line and I also didn't know I had 5 min to edit a comment.

What I meant to say was that you could do two things: use intents or handlers to communicate with the service. 

With intents you should look up how to register a broadcast receiver ( remember to put an intent filter in the manifest)

With handlers you should check out this example in the api:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample

I think the easier way would be to use the handler. Please tell me how it goes Im curious

Comment: Hi Gonzo! I've now implemented a receiver and created an instance of AlarmManager. As I see it (only tested for a couple of seconds now) the service I used earlier isn't needed. I just start the alarmmanager in my main activity and places my refresh method in the receiver, correct?

Comment: That sounds about right. If you're getting your data from the network remember to separate the network requests from the main thread so that your app remains responsive. BTW the thing about handlers in the other comment is completely wrong(oops). The intents part is correct though.